# Chrome Extension - Append link element before body

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple JS script that appends a link element to a page's header.

```
var stylesheet = document.createElement("link");
stylesheet.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
stylesheet.setAttribute("href", chrome.extension.getURL("stylesheet.css"));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to append this link right before the body tag of the page. For example:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<(some other code that may be placed)/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use .after() or .before() Jquery methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .after or .before functions in jQuery:

```
$("head").after(yourLink);
```

Will result to:

```
<head>...</head>
<link rel="foobar" />
<body>...</body>
```

EDIT: Without jQuery with same result

```
document.querySelector("html").insertBefore(yourLink, document.body);
```

Comment: Also, another quick question. How do you go about inserting it right before the end of an HTML document?

Comment: Between </body> and </html>?, document.querySelector("html").appendChild(yourLink);